# Calculate value of symbolic equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have following MATLAB code:

```
>> syms x
>> z = 20.*exp(x)+cos(x)
>> derivative = diff(z)
```

How can I calculate value of derevative for any number, e.g. 6?

Following commands

```
>> clear all
>> x = 6
>> derevative = 20*exp(x)-sin(x)
```

works fine, but if x is symbolic I don't use x = 6 such as above example.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to do this is the following:

```
syms x
z = 20.*exp(x)+cos(x)
derivative = diff(z)
subs(derivative, 6)
```

where the last line `subs(derivative, 6)` does the job, you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
syms x;
z = 20.*exp(x)+cos(x);
derivative = diff(z);
x = 5;
result = eval(derivative)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a [tutorial on how to do symbolic computation in MATLAB.](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~strickla/M340/sym.html) From what I understand, it is a bit unorthodox to use MATLAB for symbolic computations, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function given below:

```
syms a b
subs(cos(a) + sin(b), [a, b], [sym('alpha'), 2])
```

it works perfect.